# Change column values by program in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have an input like this:

```
12 abc 13 14
13 def 14 15
1  lce 22 14
```

And I want to change it by applying the program `./program` to the second column:

```
12 P1 13 14
13 P2 14 15
1  P3 22 13
```

(if `echo "abc" | ./program` returns "P1",`echo "def" | ./program` returns "P2", etc.). How I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a while read loop:

```
while read -r one two rest
do
  echo "$one $(./program <<< "$two") $rest"
done < inputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while read a b c d ; do echo $a $(./program <<< $b) $c $d ; done < t
```

where `t` is the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want as an awk script

```
{
   "echo "$2" | ./program" | getline result;
   $2 = result;
   print;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not take all in `awk`, do you need the "program"?

```
awk 'BEGIN {n=split("abc def lce",q," ");for (i=1;i<=n;i++) d[q[i]]="P"i} {sub($2,d[$2])}8' file
12 P1 13 14
13 P2 14 15
1  P3 22 14
```

---

How it works

```
awk '
BEGIN {                             # Begin block
    n=split("abc def lce",q," ")    # split the list of data in to array "q" and set "n" to number of elements
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)              # loop trough  all elements
        d[q[i]]="P"i                # assing P1, P2 etc to first, second element "d[abc]=P1" etc
    } 
    {sub($2,d[$2])}                 # change filed 2 to new element
    8                               # print the new line
    ' file                          # input file
```

---

If table with "P" data is not sequel, you can add it just like other table:

```
awk 'BEGIN {n=split("abc def lce",q," ");split("P2 Q4 A3",r," ");for (i=1;i<=n;i++) d[q[i]]=r[i];print d["def"]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be with a while loop.

```
while read -r line; do
    old="$(echo "$line" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)"
    new="$(echo "$old" | ./program)"
    echo "$line" | sed "s/$old/$new/"
done
```

Remarks:

- I use `tr` because your columns might be aligned. `tr -s ' '` replaces multiple spaces by one.
- I'm using sed to change your line, in order not to mess with the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

**WITH REGARDS TO:** *if `echo "abc" | ./program` returns "P1", `echo "def" | ./program` returns "P2", etc.). How I can do that?*

The **program** script might look something like:

```
INFILE=input.txt ## your input file

## exits if no standard input
if [ -t 0 ] ; then echo "Error: No STDIN" && exit ; fi

## do something
while read line; do
    awk -v input=$line '$2 == input {print "P"NR}' $INFILE
done
```

- after you specify the `INFILE` in the program script...
- `echo "abc" | sh program` returns "P1"
- `echo "def" | sh program` returns "P2"

---

**WHEREAS:** if you just want the output to be

```
12 P1 13 14  
13 P2 14 15  
1  P3 22 13
```

You can use the following one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {$2="P"NR}1' input.txt > outfile.txt
```

Comment: The `awk` solution is not good.  OP like to look up the value in an external script and replace in the file, not just number the line.

Comment: Sorry, but could you clarify what you mean? ... Oh, do you mean the "program" script is already written ..?

Comment: He like to change some text to some other text based on a table stored in his program.  Eks if "qwr" change to "P84AA", not just a counting number,